# echo array on <<< END

Tags: php

How can I echo an array when using this syntax?

```
echo <<< END
<p>$listing['User']['firstname']</p>
END;
```

The code above is giving me an error message. Seems like if the array is 1 level deep, removing the quotes in the attribute works, but not when it is 2 level deep array like the one I have above.

Comment: You didn't read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Why not? Also, you've been here for over three years so please stop writing tags in all of your titles.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, sorry that my question annoys you. To answer your question, sometimes it's not about not reading the docs. I read the doc here http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php, which doesn't say anything about printing array. It's easy to find the answer if you know the terminology. I haven't even heard about the terminology "nowdoc syntax" until you pasted that link. So thanks for that.

Comment: As for why I write tags on my titles? Just go to ur profile page http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit, and tell me if it is easier to know the context of your questions with the tags or not. 3 months from now, would your question "Iterator invalidation rules" makes more sense or "C++ - Iterator invalidation rules" makes more sense? Iterator can be any languages, and your summary page doesn't show the tags of your question.

Comment: Irrelevant. We already have an indexed, searchable tags system. Re-inventing tags in titles is noise. [Please do not do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/155739). (That the summary page doesn't show the tags is arguably a design flaw in the page, but the solution is _not_ to mangle the titles of questions in the database to workaround it.)

Comment: `I haven't even heard about the terminology "nowdoc syntax" until you pasted that link` You mean you used strings in PHP without reading the documentation page for strings in PHP? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
echo <<<END
<p>{$listing['User']['firstname']}</p>
END;
```